# Svelte 3 submitted form does not update input values

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I have a Svelte component displaying modal dialog with "edit" type of form. The dialog is not displayed by default. User can open it by clicking on an "edit" button on the page. This shows the form. Once the form is submitted, it disappears (Svelte prop is set to false). This is all OK. The problem is that although the form was submitted with new values and everything was properly updated on the backend, if the user reopens the dialog/form again, input fields contain the old/original values. Any hints what I have to do to get the already submitted values also there? My understanding is that this may be caused by the fact that the form (`modalContent`) is passed down as a property:

```
<script>
    export let modalContent;
    // ...
    function close()
    {
        modalVisible = false;
    }
    // ...
</script>

{#if modalVisible}
<div id="modal">
    <div id="modal-backdrop" in:fade={{duration: 100}} out:fade={{duration: 300}} on:click={close} />

    <div id="modal-content-wrapper" in:scale={{duration: 150, start: 0.8}} out:scale={{duration: 100, start: 0.8}} on:introend={onIntroEnd}>
        <div id="modal-header">
            <div class="titlebutton-close" on:click={close}/>
            <div class="flex justify-center">
                <slot name="header">
                    <!-- fallback -->
                    <h1>Modal Heading Goes Here...</h1>
                </slot>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="modal-content" bind:innerHTML={modalContent}  contenteditable="true"/>

        <div id="modal-footer">
            <slot name="footer"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{/if}
```

Submitting is done typically with `XMLHttpRequest` so probably nothing special here:

```
    // ...
    if (form.checkValidity())
    {
        // Prepare XHR
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(submitMethod, submitUrl);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        xhr.onreadystatechange = async function ()
        {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4)
            {
                if (xhr.status === 200)
                {
                    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    switch (response.command)
                    {
                        case "close":
                            close();
                            break;

                        case "replace":
                            modalContent = response.data;
                            await tick();
                            initFormElements();
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Error processing request: " + xhr.status);
                }
            }
        };

        xhr.send(new FormData(form));
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Comment: What is your `close` function doing? Once you set `modalVisible` to false, it should unload / destroy its content.

Comment: `close()` only sets the `modalVisible` property to `false` – added to the snippet above. Maybe that's exactly what I am missing... how should it unload/destroy the content?

Comment: I see. In this case, its `modalContent` which keeps the input values in store. Why are you binding the `innerHTML` instead of using slots? Whats the default value of `modalContent`? You will need to set `modalContent` to its default value when closing.

Comment: `innerHTML` is used because back-end can reject the submission (has thorough and complex validation there) and send the form back along with highlighted error fields, etc. In such case the inner HTML is replaced with the stuff sent back by the server in response.

Comment: I still recommend to switch to Json. Handling HTML on the server side can be a pain when updating the UI or during troubleshooting for example. Apart from that, the solution is to set the `modalContent` to its default value which contains empty input fields.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240416/discussion-between-silverdr-and-miwin).